# Use mix-blend-mode on the div below the absolute positioned div on hover

Tags: css

I would like to use mix-blend-mode:darken on the image of the pineapple so that it will have a blue overlay and the darkened image on hover. The trouble is that I have an absolute positioned div on top of the image. I tried applying the blue background to the absolute positioned .overlay div and applying the blend mode to that as well as wrapping the image in a div and applying the blend mode to that div but because the overlay is positioned on top, the hover does not apply the darken style. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please let me know if my details aren't clear. I added how I would like the image to display on hover in a second div #result. Is it possible to do this with just CSS?

```css
<style>
.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: static;
}

.darken img:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 7px;
    right: 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: #007bff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}

.text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;

}

#result {

  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

#result img:hover {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="darken">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  </div>
    <div class="overlay">
     <span class="text">Click Here</span>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Below is how I would like the image to display on hover but with the text on top:</p>
<div id="result">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

> In CSS, ::after creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.

### You could use an `::after` element.

This would allow you to use the same `#result` example you provided, and achieve the effect very simply.

```css
.result {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result img {
  display: block;
}

.result:hover img {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.result:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-message);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="result" data-message="New Text!">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple"   width="300" height="300">
</div>

<div class="result" data-message="Something else!">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple"   width="300" height="300">
</div>

<div class="result" data-message="click here!">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple"   width="300" height="300">
</div>
```

Comment: This was a great solution, and very elegant, however I forgot to mention that there are multiple boxes and I need to be able to update the "click here" text in the html for each so I went a different direction but will definitely use this in the future. Thank you!

Comment: @Jenny, you are actually able to access HTML attributes in CSS,  I've updated my answer to reflect this requirement.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#css_access

Comment: That is perfect, I will be swapping my code, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use another element for the blue overlay. Below I am relying on the container pseudo element.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 0;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
}
/* common styles to the text overlay and color overlay */
.container:before,
.overlay{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
/* color overlay */
.container:before {
  background-color: #007bff;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
/* text overlay */
.overlay {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
.text {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* make both visible on hover */
.container:hover .overlay,
.container:hover:before {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
  <div class="overlay">
    <span class="text">Click Here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to be able to edit the "click here" text for multiple boxes, so I went with this approach.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.overlay {
       position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor:pointer;
}


      .text {
          color: white;
          font-size: 18px;
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 2.5rem;
          mixed-blending-mode: initial;
        }
        
.overlay:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .overlay:hover + img {
        mix-blend-mode: multiply;
        transform: scale(1.2); 
        transition: .3s;
}

.darken {
 background-color: #007BFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="darken">
      <div class="overlay">
         <span class="text">Click Here</span>
      </div>
      <img class="hover-shadow cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```